# Why is DelayedJob is ignoring delayed_job_config.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have the following:

/config/delayed_job_config.rb

```
# Enable DelayedJob Logging
Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger
Delayed::Worker.logger.auto_flushing = 1

# Do not delete failed jobs (default is true)
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false

# Dont wait so long between jobs
Delayed::Worker.read_ahead = 100 # default was 5
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 1 #default was 5
```

Problem here is the settings are not being used:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.5)
1.9.3-p125 :001 > Delayed::Worker.read_ahead
 => 5 
1.9.3-p125 :002 > Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay
 => 5
```

Any ideas what's wrong here? Thanks

Comment: What makes you think it should be reading that file? Did you mean to put it in config/initializers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration goes in:

`config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb`

Documentation is [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#gory-details).